# Java parsing some dates incorrectly even though they're valid

Tags: java, android, date

An app I'm working on has to parse a large number of dates to perform some calculations on. These are being pulled out of a local SQLite database, and parsed when they are turned into Java objects. This is working fine across the entire app, but it is resulting in some very unusual behaviour in one case.

The screen that is being loaded retrieves a fairly large amount of data (testing at the moment with ~3k records) and during the process of parsing the dates, some of them are being parsed incorrectly, even though the date string itself is completely valid.

The parsing code looks like this

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

try {
  String dateString = cursor.getString(idx);
  Date d = df.parse(dateString);
  System.out.println("Parsed " + dateString + " into " + d);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

This works for most of the dates, but a few examples where this has failed are

```
Parsed 2016-11-30T10:32:29Z into Wed Nov 30 10:32:28 GMT+00:00 2016
Parsed 2016-11-30T10:48:15Z into Thu Jan 01 01:00:14 GMT+00:00 1970
Parsed 2016-11-30T10:32:30Z into Wed Nov 30 10:32:29 GMT+00:00 2016
Parsed 2016-11-30T10:48:16Z into Fri Jan 01 00:48:15 GMT+00:00 2016
Parsed 2016-11-30T10:32:31Z into Wed Nov 30 10:32:30 GMT+00:00 2016
Parsed 2016-11-30T10:48:17Z into Fri Jan 01 00:48:16 GMT+00:00 2016
Parsed 2016-11-30T10:32:32Z into Wed Nov 30 10:32:31 GMT+00:00 2016
Parsed 2016-11-30T10:32:33Z into Thu Jan 01 01:00:32 GMT+00:00 1970
Parsed 2016-11-30T10:48:18Z into Wed Nov 30 10:48:17 GMT+00:00 2016
```

As you can see, there are a number of dates that have been parsed completely incorrectly, and I'm stumped as to why.

The only thing I can think of is threading. I have two background threads which are both going to be calling this same code at the same time, although I don't see why they should interfere with one another.

Has anyone got any clue what is going on here as I'm completely lost at this point?

Comment: Is your `df` shared between the two threads? That would explain it, as `DateFormat` isn't thread-safe.

Comment: wow. Didn't realise something like a date formatter/parser would not be thread safe. Ah well, time to refactor

Comment: @JonSkeet got it sorted with ThreadLocal variables wrapping the date formatters. Appears to be working as expected now.

Answer (score -1):

you should use `semaphore` for controlling thread access

[Semaphore](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)

Comment: No, it's better to simply create a new `SimpleDateFormat` in each thread. The two threads aren't logically dealing with shared mutable data - it's just the thread-unsafe nature of `SimpleDateFormat` which is causing a problem. There's no need for coordination between the threads.